# Error when concatenating 3 variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am getting the current glucose readings from a patient system that i am developing. I used java script to get the current date/time and past it through form hidden fields. In the script below i have stored the date parts in 3 separate variables and then i concatinate them into 1, so that i can use that in the insert query for mysql.  The error i am getting is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' 
Hope someone can find the mistake, as i do not understand what i'm doing wrong by putting ',' between variables. Here is the code:

```
<?
SESSION_START();
include("DatabaseConnection.php");
//gather form data into variables
//gather parts of the date from hidden input fields
$Day = $_POST['Day'];
$Month = $_POST['Month'];
$Year = $_POST['Year'];

$Date = $Year, "-", $Month, "-", $Day; //line with error
//get hours and minutes from hidden fields
$Minutes = $_POST['Minutes'];
$Hours = $_POST['Hours'];
//concatinate date into 1 variable
$Time = $Hours, ":", $Minutes;

$GlucoseLevel = $_POST['GlucoseLevel'];
$SBP = $_POST['SBP'];
$DBP = $_POST['DBP'];
$Comments = $_POST['Comments'];
//store current user's id
$User_id = $_SESSION['User_id'];
//query for inserting reading
$ReadingInsert = "insert into reading
(Reading_id,
User_id,
Date,
Time,
GlucoseLevel,
SBP,
DBP,
Comments)
values(null,
'$User_id',
'$Date',
'$Time',
'$GlucoseLevel',
'$SBP',
'$DBP',
'$Comments')";

//run insert query
mysql_query($ReadingInsert) or die("Cannot insert reading");
`enter code here`mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: String concatenation is done with periods not commas. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: The error tells you that in php you dont use , to concat. Change for dots. Also, with a javascript date you depends on the client hour. Mysql already have functions to get date and time, i sugest you search them.

Comment: @EvanMulawski How do you learn basic syntax of a new language? It wouldn't be by trying to use it in quick and dirty 10 line script would it?

Comment: @Louis My point was: using MySQL queries in PHP before learning how to concatenate strings is not the way to go.

Comment: @EvanMulawski His SQL wasn't the problem. Whats wrong with learning a language with useful code? Why are you assuming this is his first language? How about instead of trying to defend your dickish and absurd position you just delete *that* comment as well?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP you use `.` to concatenate strings, try:

```
$Date = $Year . "-" . $Month  "-" . $Day;
```

see:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation in php uses `.` not `,` [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs)

Answer (score 0):

```
$Date = $Year, "-", $Month, "-", $Day; //line with error
```

should be

```
$Date = $Year. "-". $Month. "-". $Day;  //<- Full "." and no ","
```

Comment: thank you @BabyAzerty . Nifty, please accept my apologies for the mistake

Comment: I'm not attacking you personally :s, just informing you :D. I've removed my downvote :) (that `-1` is some other dude's)

Comment: aah I do not worry abt the downvote, just that I committed a mistake so apologized for it

Comment: There is still another line that needs to be fixed, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/sprintf) to interpolate strings with variables:

```
$Date = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $Year, $Month, $Day); 
$Time = sprintf('%s:%s', $Hours, $Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time I really use escaped concatenation is to use a function, else curly brackets `{}` are your friend!

`$Date = "{$Year}-{$Month}-{$Day}";`

You don't have to worry about forgetting periods or running into awkward `"'"` situations. Love curly brackets... LOVE THEM!

Comment: I know it's personal preference, but I never cared for brackets. I think it's because most IDEs don't highlight variables contained within brackets, as they are treated like strings.